# How do C++ static and dynamic memory leak detection tools work?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

How do C++ static and dynamic memory leak detection tools work? Does passing a memory leak detection test by these tools mean that there is NO chance of memory leaks in a program?

Comment: Not to divert the topic of the question, but for the second question, that's the job of the programmer to manage carefully resources. That means using a good automatic resource management mechanism like RAII whose patterns are much more predictable than manually managing resources. Always have problems solved at coding time first and you'll less likely to use those leak detection tools.

Comment: Thanks, I know its the programmer's job. I was just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static test basically looks at the source code, and attempts to find a matching `delete` for every `new` (and `free` for every `malloc`).

Most dynamic tests mark each block of memory as its allocated to indicate what code allocated that block. Then when the program is shutting down, they look for blocks in the heap that haven't been deleted yet. If they find any, they print out the data to indicate what code allocated the block(s) that leaked.

Both of these can fail. Many static tests can be fooled by things like exceptions, where you have code that appears to unconditionally delete what's allocated, but may not when an exception is thrown between the `new` and the matching `delete`.

Dynamic tests can be fooled by (for only one easy example) your failing to test a code path that leaks memory. They only track memory allocated by the code paths you exercise during execution, so if there's an allocation you don't exercise, they can't provide any information about that memory being deleted.